# multiple check boxes in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, checkbox

In component I have define checkboxes

```
public groceries = [
{ name: 'Seitan', bought: false },
{ name: 'Almond Meal Flour', bought: false },
{ name: 'Organic Eggs', bought: false }
];
```

In model I make groceries as string

```
export class User {
 id: number,
 email: string,
 password: string,
 firstName: string,
 lastName: string,
 groceries: string,
 }
```

component.html

```
<span *ngFor="let grocery of groceries">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="groceries" [(ngModel)]="user.groceries" 
        [value]="grocery.name">
        {{grocery.name}}
        </label>
      </span>
```

Issue is that by this when I select one checkbox all others are selected. I am confuse and not on track to implement this checkbox feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bind a number of checkboxes to the same `user.groceries`.

Either bind them to a property of `grocery` (the iteration variable of `*ngFor`, or create another array where you bind each checkbox to a different array entry.

```
  <span *ngFor="let grocery of groceries">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="groceries" [(ngModel)]="grocery.isChecked" 
    {{grocery.name}}
    </label>
  </span>
```

or

```
checkedGroceries = new Array(groceries.length);
```

```
  <span *ngFor="let grocery of groceries; let i=index">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="groceries" [(ngModel)]="checkedGroceries[i]" 
    {{grocery.name}}
    </label>
  </span>
```

You don't need `[value]`. The value is assinged already by `[(ngModel)]="..."`

Comment: is there any issue in groceries:string? bcz if I select multiple groceries how it will submit?

Comment: I don't know what "In model I make groceries as string" means. Your question doesn't show anything about a form, therefore I don't understand how this is related to submit.

Comment: basically I want to submit it in comma separated

Comment: but not understand how to do it

Comment: You need to provide more concrete information if you want me to provide guidance. Please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Update...i post my models also...you can groceries as string in model.....

Comment: I want when i submit groceries with comma come in user.groceries